# Wait for onload when running JS embedded in AJAX loaded element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Assume you load the contents of a div via AJAX. Assume it contain various elements and JS code modifying this elements.

Does the script have to wait for onload to trigger or is it safe just to start modifying the DOM immediately after? Is the following example safe?

```
<form id="foo">...</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#foo").bar();
</script>
```

Or must I always do the following:

```
<form id="foo">...</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#foo").bar();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you have an asynchronous request that returns HTML with embedded Scripts in it and  add that to the DOM the scripts won't run.  jQuery, however, has functionality in its ajax code that will parses out these embedded scripts and executes them.

From [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Different data handling can be
>   achieved by using the dataType option.
>   Besides plain xml, the dataType can be
>   html, json, jsonp, script, or text.
>
> The text and xml types return the data
>   with no processing. The data is simply
>   passed on to the success handler,
>   either through the responseText or
>   responseXML property of the
>   XMLHttpRequest object, respectively.
>
> Note: We must ensure that the MIME
>   type reported by the web server
>   matches our choice of dataType. In
>   particular, XML must be declared by
>   the server as text/xml or
>   application/xml for consistent
>   results.
>
> If html is specified, any embedded
>   JavaScript inside the retrieved data
>   is executed before the HTML is
>   returned as a string. Similarly,
>   script will execute the JavaScript
>   that is pulled back from the server,
>   then return the script itself as
>   textual data.

Since jQuery will execute the scripts first, the embedded script code will run before the html is ever added to the dom.  To get around this you should return your JavaScript code wrapped as a function:

```
function doAfterLoad() {
// ...
}
```

And then just call this function in the success callback of the load or ajax methods.

```
('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  doAfterLoad();
});
```

Comment: When I try this, I get yelled at (firebug) that "doAfterLoad()" does not exist. Help?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code that reproduces your issue to jsfiddle.net?